# Loss of class attributes whilst multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using parallel processing in Python for the first time and am encountering some behaviour I do not quite understand.

In the minimum reproducible code (below), I create 2 instances of an object. These objects are, initially, initialised with an empty list. I then, 10 times, use parallel processing to append a new random number to each list for both of my objects.

What I do not understand is why the list are seemingly empty. By using print statements I have examined my code and can see that the objects are only initialised once, hence, I am confused why the lists remain empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

class my_class:

    def __init__(self,id):

        self.id = id
        self.awesome_list = []

    def update_list(self):

        self.awesome_list.append(random.randint(0,9))

def worker_func(obj):

    obj.update_list()

def main():

    my_objs = [my_class(1),my_class(2)]

    for i in range(10):

        with Pool() as pool:

            pool.starmap(worker_func,zip(my_objs))
            pool.close()
            pool.join()

    # Examine awesome_list for each my_class object
    for ob in my_objs:

        print(ob.id)
        print(ob.awesome_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: those objects *are never modified in your program*. Multiprocessing *creates multiple processes*. Just like if you opened up a terminal, did `python myscript.py`, then opened up *another* terminal, and did `python myscript.py` again. Different processes do not share state, the multiprocessing library handles the inter-process communication and the serializing (with pickle) of objects that are being passed as arguments to the function and the return values of the function

Comment: thank you for the fast reply - how would I modify my code to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your `worker_func` should *return some value*, this will be serialized in the worker process, then sent to the main process automatically. That is generally how you should approach multiprocessing - use pure functions, don't rely on shared state

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. For architectural reasons I would prefer not to change my (much larger) code at this point (of which this is a much more stripped down version) - would there be any way to be able to append to the list attributes at all? If not, would you mind explaining what the code might look like if I were to modify it in line with your suggestion? cheers

Comment: you need to *return the obejcts* and then retrieve the result of `pool.map`, which returns a list of the results. But note, this may not actually speed up your code, since what you are doing here would almost certainly be slower than just appending serially in the main process - the work you are doing in each subprocess needs to be worth the IPC overhead

Comment: Otherwise, you need to look into how to [share state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) between processes. All of this is discussed in the docs. Note, sharing state between processes is always a pain

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed feedback - I will take a look at my code and try to fix the issues. On your last comment, yes you are correct - the larger code takes additional arguments from another list.